# Jmeter execution decrease the number of request on AWS upon adding HTTP Cache Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

Hello can anyone help me how to simulate this scenario

Currently I have Constant Throughput Timer = 60 and per minute I'm able to generate 6000 request per minute without cache manager. upon adding cache manager I noticed the request went down to 1,500 request per minute upon checking on AWS Cloudwatch. but If I run locally using debug sampler I'm able to generate 6,000 request per minute. do you have any idea about this problem. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much

-I want to achieve 6000 request per minute

-Randomized user_id (I have 10,000 pool of user_id)

-But only 1 cache for entire execution is this possible?

-I'm currently using GET Method here's my sample payload

/test/?user_id=${user_id}&query_type=existing_user

Jmeter Screenshot run locally with Cache Manager as Debug Sample Processor not actually request since I cannot invoke locally, I can only access via EC2 Instance:

[image: Jmeter result]

AWS Result Before Adding HTTP Cache Manager -(If you sum up Cache Hit and Miss you will get roughly 6000 request)
[image]

AWS Result After adding HTTP Cache Manager:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly how HTTP Cache Manager should work, it tells JMeter to respect [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) headers hence JMeter sends [HEAD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) request and checks if the page has changed since last visit and if it hasn't - the actual request is not being made. This is an essential part of [configuring JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)

If you're not happy with the behaviour or it doesn't match your load pattern you can tick "Clear cache each iteration" box in the HTTP Cache Manager:

[image]

Or alternatively untick `Same user on each iteration` box in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group):

[image]